# Catch redirection and make it go to an iframe

Tags: javascript, scripting, greasemonkey, browser-extension

I'm trying to use [Diigo](http://www.diigo.com/tools/toolbar) with sciencedirect.com but apparently the pages are not static, they keep changing, but I can access the same paper through the same link every time. The problem is that this link then redirects the page to a dynamic one in science direct.

I was thinking, is it possible through JavaScript or Greasemonkey to catch the redirection and send it to an iframe, so that the main page could be the initial link?

An example:

http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0924-8579(95)90674-L

Answer (score 0):

> I was tinking, is it possible trhough javascript on greasemonkey to catch the redirection and send it to an iframe, so that the main page could be the initial link?

No it's not possible to do this with Greasemoneky, you'd have to use a Firefox add-on in order to do this.

Comment: But arren't the firefox plugins javascript?

Comment: add-ons have access to more apis

Comment: @Carlos Familia:  You will probably have to write your own add-on, although the one called, ["Redirector,"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) seems close to what you want.